# How do i get a dictionary of all variables defined in the scope of a function?

Tags: python, dictionary, inspect

So i want to get every variable from a function as a dictionary. Like this:

```py
from typing import Any

def myfunc():
  var1 = 10
  var2 = 20
  var3 = 30
  var4 = '40'
  var5 = False

x: dict[str, Any] = myfunc.vars
hardtyped_x = { # What i want x to be. Not including parameters
  'var1': 10,
  'var2': 20,
  'var3': 30,
  'var4': '40',
  'var5': False
}
```

I tried asking tabnine and got something along the lines of:

```py
import inspect

def myfunc():
  var1 = 10
  var2 = 20
  var3 = 30
  var4 = '40'
  var5 = False

x = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
```

but this either raises an error (as currentframe() can return None and this raises an error) or i get a long list of dunder methods and other things of the sort

Comment: This seems like something you generally shouldn't want to do - can you explain why you want to do this? Or perhaps it's a case of the [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Knowing the assignments to local variables in a function is useless, because they can't be accessed from outside the function.  The only conceivable place where `inspect` might tell you anything useful is from within a function *called by* `myfunc()`.

Comment: You could get the names of the local variables as `myfunc.__code__.co_varnames`, but not their values. The values are hardcoded in the byte code that runs and does the initial assignment. And you certainly couldn't get any computed values as that would happen per function call. If the goal is to return all of the local variables on each function call, then `return locals()`.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out a psuedo way to do it:

```
from types import FunctionType
import inspect

def getFunctionDefinedVariables(function: FunctionType) -> dict:
    with open("TEMPORARYFILE.py", "w") as f:
        codeblock = inspect.getsource(function)
        codeblock = remove_indents_and_top_line
        f.write(codeblock)
        imported_temp_file = __import__("TEMPORARYFILE.py")
        return {key: val for key, val in imported_temp_file.__dict__.items() if not (key.startswith('__') and key.endswith('__'))}
```

Will update once im done making the full function

Edit:
JK found a different way to do what i wanted

Edit2: JK again i made it anyway for a different project

```
import inspect
import os

from types import FunctionType
from typing import Any
from textwrap import dedent
from importlib import import_module as imp
from importlib import invalidate_caches as inv
from time import sleep

def getFunctionDefinedVariables(function: FunctionType) -> dict[str, Any]:
    with open("TEMPORARYFILE.py", "w") as f:
        sleep(10.0)
        f.write("\n".join([dedent(string) for string in inspect.getsource(function).split("\n")[1:]]))
    inv()
    try:
        import TEMPORARYFILE as imported_temp_file
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("Error making temp.")
    items = imported_temp_file.__dict__.items()
    os.remove("TEMPORARYFILE.py")
    return {key: val for key, val in items if not (key.startswith('__') and key.endswith('__'))}
        
    
def test():
    x = None
    y = 1
    z = "2"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for key, val in getFunctionDefinedVariables(test).items():
        print(f"{key}: {val}")
```

Comment: no, this won't work. at least not for, say, functions with parameters, or functions that reference global variables.

Comment: im just trying to get the varibles defined in the function, not global variables or parameters

Comment: Yes. But this will raise `NameError`s if you execute a function that has any of those.